# Iterate through excel files and extract specific range of data and add it to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do an automation in python and I need to iterate through all excel files in a folder and look for specific range of text in each excel and add it to a dataframe as a seperate column. I think I'm able to read the excel files and extract the required data but I got the result in 3 seperate pandas class dataframes.

```
filesList = ["sample1.xlsx", "sample2.xlsx", "sample3.xlsx"]

for file in filesList:
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    data_rows = []
    for row in ws['C6':'C9']:
        data_cols = []
        for cell in row:
            data_cols.append(cell.value)
        data_rows.append(data_rows)
```

Output:

```
                0 
0             apple
1             sold
2             No stock
                0 
0             orange 
1             not sold
2             In stock
                0 
0             kiwi
1             not sold
2             In stock
```

Desired output:

```
0          1           2
apple    sold       No stock
orange   not sold   In stock
kiwi     not sold   In stock
```

Comment: I guess this is the output over multiple files? "data_rows" is reset to a new empty list for each file and the shown code doesn't store the list data anywhere.

Comment: What generates your output?  It looks like the print is also inside the for loop?  Also, where are you creating the DataFrame?  There's not one in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
files = ["sample1.xlsx", "sample2.xlsx", "sample3.xlsx"]

dfs = []
for file in files:
    work_book = load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=True, data_only=True)
    data = [[x.value for x in row] for row in work_book.active["C6:C9"]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
    dfs.append(df)

df_mapping = {x: y for x, y in enumerate(dfs)}
final_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df_mapping.get(x)) for x in df_mapping]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the [DataFrame.from_records() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).  Your code seems to have two issues:

- You're not distinguishing between columns and rows of the `DataFrame`.
- You're resetting the `DataFrame` on every iteration through `filesList`.

Revised code:

```
filesList = ["sample1.xlsx", "sample2.xlsx", "sample3.xlsx"]

data_rows = [] # Stores the data that will be loaded into the DF
column_name_dict = { # Map Excel columns to DF columns
    'C6': '0',
    'C7': '1',
    'C8': '2',
}
for file in filesList:
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    for cell_ref, df_col in column_name_dict.items():
        data_cols = {}
        data_cols[df_col] = ws[cell_ref].value
        data_rows.append(data_cols)
composed_df = DataFrame.from_records(data_rows)
print(composed_df)
```